# How to unlimited to zoom in the image?

Tags: android

I am developing in Android , and implement to zoom in/out the image. I use the following code to zoom in the image.

```
 Button test1_btn = findViewById(R.id.test1_btn);
    test1_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG,"test_btn");

            sea_image.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bmp = sea_image.getDrawingCache();

            int width = bmp.getWidth();
            int height = bmp.getHeight();

            float scaleWidth = (float) 2;
            float scaleHeight = (float) 2;


            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

            Bitmap newbm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, width, height, matrix,true);

            sea_image.setImageBitmap(newbm);
        }
    });
```

And the xml of image is like the following.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sea_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/sea"/>
```

It can zoom in the image many times when I click the button. But it stop zoom in when the image's height or image's width touch the screen edge like the following.

[image]

**Question:
How to unlimited zoom in the image?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the xml? Are there any imageScale options?

Comment: @toshkinl I did not set any imageScale for image.